# Combining formulas that include "" using putexcel

Tags: excel, stata, quotations

I'm trying to save some time generating a lot of reports on Excel with a program from Stata using the `putexcel` command.

It has worked perfectly. However, I'm encountering a problem when mixing 3 formulas in which one includes quotation marks to denote a space `" "`.

To be more specific, this is the code I'm using:

```
putexcel B2=formula("IF((VLOOKUP(A2;HI!$1:$1048576;2;));" ";VLOOKUPA2;HI!$1:$1048576;2;))") using "`archivo'", modify sheet("DEFGGF")
```

The problem here is that it works in Excel, but instead of the space enclosed in `" "` I'm getting a `0` since it doesn't read the quotation marks.

I have tried enclosing the `""` in several other ways, like

```
'""`
```

or

```
"'"'`"`"
```

but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment, but I never am able to get the backtick (`) character to display properly in a comment.

I think your code should look like

```
putexcel B2=formula(`"IF((VLOOKUP(...));" ";VLOOKUP(...))"') using ...
```

but I admit to not having tested this solution. But the general principles involved are explained in the output of the Stata command `help quotes##double`.

Comment: A literal left tick on SO (outside code formatted as such) requires a previous backslash as escape character. I got this `\`foo'` by left tick -- backslash -- left tick -- foo -- right tick -- left tick. Here the -- are separators, not to be typed. (It took a long time here for me to stumble across this, although no doubt it's documented somewhere.)